# Date is in string format

Tags: javascript, date, time

I am a newbie in javascript, come to my question.

I am using ionic 2 build application in which i am using date time picker for taking a time. 
I am getting a a time format is in the "hh:mm" using time picker. eg(10:11) which is in string format and i am using Date() function which give me date is in something like

```
"Mon Aug 01 2016 01:32:03 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)"
```

I want to replace "hh:mm"(01:32) from Date object with my string output of "hh:mm"(10:11) and then want to convert that into new Date object.

I also tried split and slice function but doesn't work.

If i get some guide about this will be very helpful.

I will be very helpful to all of you.
thanks

Comment: use `new Date()` to get a date object which you can work with, set the hour and minute as you like, then output the string

Comment: Removed the PHP tag from your question as it had nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [read up on Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

In your case, the following code is a starting point.

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours('10');
d.setMinutes('11');
```

Of course, you should exchange `'10'` and `'11'` with your picker data. Also, there are many other methods you can use on the `Date` object.